# Lumia 810 not showing option to change internet APN

Tags: cellular-data

I recently purchased an unlocked **Lumia 810** from eBay. It is unlocked from T-Mobile and I am using it with Wind Mobile in Canada.

Everything is working fine until I discovered that I could not get data probably because my phone has T-Mobile settings in it.

I went to `Settings` > `Cellular` and tried looking for an option to change APN settings (I have successfully done this on other Windows Phones).

To my surprise, I didn't have any options available to change APN settings. This is what I saw:

[image]
[image]

There is nothing after the `sim applications` button.

Anyone have any ideas as to why the APN settings button isn't available or a work around?

Other specs:

Software: Windows Phone 8.0
OS version: 8.0.10327.77

---

**Edit 1:** In an effort to try and address the situation, I updated the OS to 8.0.10512.142. The problem still persists

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround to be able to input my APN settings, I download the [Nokia Access Point](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/access-point/ce3895c7-01d0-4daf-a4c3-25c10463942d) app which adds a new options under `Settings` called `access point` which allows me to define a new Internet/MMS APN.

To get this app, scan this QR code:

[image]

Comment: In my case this app came with my carrier configs even though my phone is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the APN settings are available in the `Access Point` settings not in the `Cellular` settings. To access that go to:

`Settings` -> `Access Point`. It is the last options in the settings menu.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have `access point` in settings. I'm guessing that's carrier specific.

Comment: @karancan My device is unlocked. It is not bound to a specific carrier.

Comment: I don't have any other explanation for why you can see that option and I can't. I am now in the process of updating my software to GDR 3. Let's see if that helps.

Comment: @karancan that should work perfectly since GDR3 is generic.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: I found this: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpnetwork/apn-is-missing-in-the-phone-settings-of-nokia/dd2c5c99-919d-4754-baf4-4eabf46bf4ef